# How would I shorthand this strict equality expression

Tags: javascript, equality

Is there any way to shorthand the `if` expression without introducing a new variable?

```
if ((c2 === 'RED') || (c2 === 'GREEN') || (c2 === 'BLUE')) {
 return true;
} else {
 return false
}
```

I figured it would be something like:
`if ((c2 === ('RED'|| 'GREEN' ||'BLUE')))`

Comment: No, your original is the best you can do with comparison operators. An alternative would be to set up the values as property names in an object and test `c2` as a property name.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.indexOf` does strict checking, so you could do

```
if ( ['RED','GREEN','BLUE'].indexOf(c2) !== -1 ) {...
```

and as it already returns a boolean, you could just return it directly without the condition

Comment: Golf'd: `['RED','GREEN','BLUE'].includes(c2)`

Comment: Golfed more `new Set(['RED','GREEN','BLUE']).has(c2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it by taking advantage of the fact that the comparisons give you boolean results, so you don't need an explicit `return` with the boolean value:

```
return ((c2 === 'RED') || (c2 === 'GREEN') || (c2 === 'BLUE'));
```

You can also make an object:

```
var targets = { RED: 1, GREEN: 1, BLUE: 1 };
return !!targets[c2]; // !! turns the 1 into true
```

(You could use `true` in the object to avoid the `!!`.)

Comment: The variable isn't necessary: `return !!{ RED: 1, GREEN: 1, BLUE: 1 }[c2];` but that's getting pretty hard to read.

Comment: or `c2 in { RED: 1, GREEN: 1, BLUE: 1 }`

Comment: IMO using an array seems easier here, since `includes` or `indexOf` return boolean (ish, truthy/falsy on indexOf) is easier than a double NOT operation. Doesn't mean you're not wrong though, just different methods, all work

Comment: @SterlingArcher right; I have a deep-seated superstition that object property lookup is faster than array search, but for three values it absolutely doesn't matter so either is fine.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - bonus points for saying "Doesn't mean you're not wrong" in a comment about making something easier than a double NOT operation (even though that kind of means "you're wrong").